# admob firebase_admob:verifyReleaseResources error

Tags: flutter, admob

I am getting the error during flutter build apk for dependency firebase_admob- 0.5.5, but it runs perfectly on run command .
The error on terminal during flutter build is-

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':firebase_admob:verifyReleaseResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
  C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:304: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSetti
ngs not found.
  C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:305: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found
.
  error: failed linking references.
```

Can anyone help me out with this issue?

Comment: Any updates? @Feisal Aswad doesn't apply in my case because I put the value already outside the activity tag

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem case. My mistake was I'm putting

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxx"/>
```

between activity tags

But it should outside activity tags